# Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, favorite

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a), I've made [a userscript](https://gist.github.com/shu8/08d86eca16fc6146e5d2) that allows you to **tag** favourites, and **add personal notes** to them (until SE implements this themselves!):

### To create favourites

When you click on the favourite star of a question, a little popup comes up, asking you which tag you want to save this question to. You will then be asked to enter a personal message (you can leave it blank if you don't want to).

A new orange star will be added after the normal yellow SE star if the question has been favourited; hovering over this will show the note (if any) that you set and clicking the star will delete the favourite.

**This does *not* change the function of SE's standard favourites system**. It only adds a new feature.

[image]

### To view favourites

On your profile's favourites tab, at the bottom of the page, you will see an added section labelled `Favourites Enhancer` - from here, you can:

- filter which tags you're viewing
- add new tags
- remove existing tags
- remove existing favourites

[image]

### The script

Get it on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/08d86eca16fc6146e5d2). You must have something like Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey installed because the script relies on a few `GM_*` features!

Please post any bug reports/feature-requests!

---

I recommend that you still use SE's favourites system, but use this as *an addition*, because, it's a userscript - and anything could happen - probably not, but better safe than sorry!

It has *no* database, data is simply saved in arrays, and as such, unfortunately you cannot *search* for favourites (but if you added a note, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> should allow you to search for the text you added (provided you remember that note...)).

The default tags have been taken from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225028/260841). The orange star has been taken from [here](http://www.clipartbest.com/clipart-4cbKkkdcg).

Comment: I've finally got it running, sort of. I have the pop up in the star in the question, but in my Favorites tab I can't see Favourites Enhancer. Running in Opera on OSX 10.8.5, using TamperMonkey -beta

Comment: @Greenonline please could you [open developer tools](https://help.opera.com/en/latest/advanced/#developerTools), and copy/paste the 'console' output here? Or if it's short, a screenshot will do!

Comment: Ah, after enabling the dev tools, The Fav Enhancer has just appeared at the bottom of the screen, I'd swear it wasn't there earlier... :-) Thanks anyway. Maybe add to your post that the Favourites enhancer appears at the bottom of the screen, The screen shot of the Favourites enhancer isn't clear where on the page it is to be found. Also, the image isn't clickable, I've just suggested an edit for that.

Comment: That's great! Not sure why enabling dev tools fixed it but I'm glad it does! Thanks for the edit :) hope you find the script useful!

Comment: I'm not sure why either, or even if it did. Maybe it caused the page to be properly refreshed/reloaded.  However, I did refresh the page multiple times before contacting you, so yeah... weird :-)

Comment: Does this still work? It doesn't seem to work on Firefox 104.0.1 with Tampermonkey 4.17.6161.

Comment: @JamesRisner Thanks for letting me know! I've just updated this now so hopefully v1.1 should work if you re-install. I made this quite a while ago and unfortunately don't have too much time right now, so the code is still quite messy and the UI is not great, sorry for that!

Comment: Note: this userscript will soon be obsolete after https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-are-evolving-into-saves goes live!